How to modify the code of a method in a Python class at runtime
I'm working on developing an acceleration framework for neural networks, using XLA to compile the computation graphs of models. However, since the code of the libraries used in models wasn't written by me, they often do not prioritize performance, which can degrade the performance of my low-level code. As a result, I'm considering adding some patches to dynamically modify parts of a model's forward function when importing my acceleration library. However, due to the need to maintain compatibility with the higher-level model libraries, I require a more flexible patching approach.
Here is the strategy I'm currently considering, but somehow it doesn't work.
I can use the inspect library to get a class's code, find the target line, replace it with another line and use exec to set modified class.
code demo using inspect is as follows:
def patch_qwen():
    import inspect
    import transformers.models.qwen2.modeling_qwen2 as qwen2
    replace_str = "        rotary_seq_len = kv_seq_len"
    search_str = "position_ids[:, -1].max().item()"
    src = inspect.getsource(qwen2.Qwen2FlashAttention2).splitlines()
    print('\n'.join(src)) # first print
    for i, line in enumerate(src):
        if search_str in line:
            # print(f"target str find {search_str} at {i}")
            src[i] = replace_str
            break
    src = '\n'.join(src)
    exec(src, qwen2.__dict__)
    src = inspect.getsource(qwen2.Qwen2FlashAttention2)
    print("------------------------------------------------")
    print(src)# second print

the result is the first print and the second print are the same, the Qwen2FlashAttention2 class doesn't change somehow.
Can anyone give me some explaination about why it doesn't work and how to solve the problem?

This will only work if you can rely on the rest of the code being what you expect it to be. At that point, why not simply define a function with the updated code (including the lines you don't want to change) and just monkey-patch that onto the class?

Can you explain in a bit more detail? My current situation is that the model's code is within the transformers library, and I can't control how this library might change in the future. I need to add some patches in my own library. What I can think of now is to find the classes that need to be patched, then match some of their code patterns (the way shown in the demo is very simple, just for demonstration purposes), and then modify them accordingly. It seems that I still need to make corresponding adjustments for subsequent versions.

somehow when I replace the serach_str with replace_str and call exec, when I use inspect.getsource to check the code, I find the code doesn't change.  Can you tell me where there is a problem with my code? What I expect is that when I call exec, the next time I call inspect.getsource, I will see the modified code

why not simply define a function with the updated code (including the lines you don't want to change) and just monkey-patch that onto the class. Because this function will call other method in the class. I can't simply replace single function, I can only replace the entire class.

Yes, that's fine.  When your patched code calls other methods, it goes through the normal lookup.

Rather than trying to edit the source code, instead, replace the method on the class with an updated version of the method (monkey patching the class).

If, for a simplified example, you have models.py containing a class:
class Model:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self._values = values
    
    def get_values(self):
        return self._values

    def total(self):
        print("Slow total")
        total = 0
        for value in self.get_values():
            total += value
        return total

and you want to patch the total function then you can monkey patch the object to replace that function:
from models import Model

def patched_total(self):
    print("Fast total")
    return sum(self.get_values())

Model.total = patched_total

Then whenever you want the total for the model it will call the patched version, rather than the original method. (Note: the other methods will not be modified. As demonstrated in the example above with the get_values method.)

If you want to be able to swap between the original and new functionality then you can monkey patch within a context manager. For example, if you have patch.py:
def patched_total(self):
    print("Fast total")
    return sum(self.get_values())

class PatchTotal:
    def __init__(self):
        from models import Model
        self.model = Model
        self.total = None
        
    def __enter__(self):
        self.total = self.model.total
        self.model.total = patched_total
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.model.total = self.total
        self.total = None

then:
from models import Model
from patch import PatchTotal

model = Model([1, 2, 3])

print(model.total())

with PatchTotal():
    print(model.total())

print(model.total())

outputs:
Slow total
6
Fast total
6
Slow total
6


Thank you for your response. However, I feel that if we need to write a patch every time the upstream library's code changes, it might add more work on us in terms of maintenance. I'm thinking if we could develop a universal method and use pattern matching to replace parts of the class code, it might save us some effort in the long-term maintenance.

Or is there any compromise between using inspect and monkey patching? For example, first use inspect to get the code, then modify it, and finally turn this code string into a function before using monkey patching.

@shadow I'm sure you could do that. However, I'm not convinced that what you are doing is the best solution - would it not be better to fork the upstream library and patch the code in the fork and then try to make a pull request on the upstream library so that your performance enhancements are included into the upstream library and everyone can make use of them (and so that you don't have to keep patching the library).

@shadow "develop a universal method and use pattern matching to replace parts of the class code" - this is simply an impossibility. You cannot predict how the other code changes. What you propose is something that would have to be able to read the current code and figure out how to modify it to get the desired result. Clearly, that's a vastly more complicated problem than simply maintaining an alternative routine. And all that is going along with the idea that all this is needed to begin with. A far more sensible approach would be to contribute to the original, or extend it.

The answer @MTO has provided here is the reasonable solution to the problem you posed. If you feel it does not meet your need, you should clarify your question with specific reasons why this cannot work, and what exactly you do need instead - not asking for magic.

@Grismar,  the answer he provides is indeed feasible, but my current issue is that, due to our underlying code needing to match different models from the upper-level transformers library, simply using monkey patching might require making many patches. Moreover, every time there is a change in the model code of the upper-level Transformers library, we might need to modify our patches, which will create significant difficulties for our long-term maintenance.

develop a universal method and use pattern matching to replace parts of the class code.  - this is simply an impossibility Although adopting pattern matching will also require modifying our patch, the frequency of modifications will be much lower. Since we just modify some code，even if the upstream code changes, our old patch can still work.
